# Leaflet.js map has extra grey space on all sides and lets me drag infinitively

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using Leaflet.js to generate a map with some layover information. I turned on the noWrap option so that the world does not repeat. However, there is a lot of unlimited grey on all sides. I can drag the area infinitely. Unfortunately, I need to have the drag functionality to get around the map when zoomed in. Has anybody run into this problem? It doesn't seem like anything I do with the CSS has any effect on the problem. Any information would be great!

Kirie

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([41.9, 12.5], 2);
            L.tileLayer(tileServerUrl, {
                attribution: tileServerAttribution,
                maxZoom: 16,
                minZoom: 2,
                noWrap: true
            }).addTo(map);
            map.keyboard.disable();
            var bounds = map.getBounds();
            var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
            var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
            bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest,northEast);
            map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Can your create jsfiddle jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use "maxbounds" to block the dragging to the bounds :
Here's a sample : https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/maxbounds/

Comment: Should I use the lats and longs from the corners of the map?

Comment: I added some code to the question. Is this the correct use of setMaxBounds? It seems to create an error and does not finish loading map content.